# What is the difference between a linear transformation and a linear vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Maybe it's just terminology that is bogging me down.  Only some vector spaces are linear since they not all vector spaces preserve linearity when adding vectors .  That is you can add the components together before you form the vector or add the vectors together and they will be equal.  So only some vector spaces are linear ? correct?

But a linear transformation says you can perform the transformation first on each vector before adding them or after adding them and the linearity is preserved.

But then are not ALL linear transformation  nothing more than subsets of the linear vector space since that property must be preserved in all cases ?

Like I said probably a semantic misunderstanding .Can anyone help?

Comment: Linear transformation is an operation, while the linear/vector space is a space; and you can do linear transformations in linear/vector spaces.

Comment: Can you give an example of a *non*linear vector space? The essential property of a vector space is its linearity.

Comment: You know I thought the same thing...what threw me  was the name "linear vector space"   If all vector spaces must be linear then why are they referred to as linear......? by introducing the word linear in front of vector space I assumed there existed some that were not. What about linear sub spaces ...can I assume all sub spaces are linear?

Comment: Well, I’ve heard of “linear space” as a synonym for “vector space,” but using both modifiers seems redundant to me. As for subspaces, it likely depends on context. When you’re working in linear algebra, then I’d say that it’s safe to make that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused between two different things. A vector space is a space and Linear transformations are maps on these vector spaces which are linear.